# Why are my Spring 3 POST arguments doubled?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a Spring 3 annotated controller and a form with a submit. The JSP has 3 hidden fields that we pass along with the submit on POST:

```
<form:form method="POST">
    <h2>param1: <c:out value="${command.param1}"/></h2>
    <h2>param2: <c:out value="${command.param2}"/></h2>
    <h1 style="display: inline">Server time: </h1><h1 style="display: inline" class="serverTime"><c:out value="${command.time}"/></h1>

    <form:hidden path="param1"></form:hidden>
    <form:hidden path="param2"></form:hidden>
    <form:hidden class="serverTime" path="time"></form:hidden>

    <input type="submit" value="Next page"/>
</form:form>
```

And this is tied to a method registered in this controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(
            Customer model, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        model.setTime(calendar.getTime().toString());
        return "test/testFinish";
}
```

Customer has 3 String fields, param1, param2, time.
And all seems to be fine, but the model at the call time of the processSubmit() has double the data..for 2/3 fields:

```
param1: value1,value1
param2: value2,value2
time: Wed Oct 23 12:57:38 PDT 2013
```

So time is fine, but the param1 and 2 are doubled.

Why is this?

---

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initForm(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
    ChrisTestFinish chrisTestFinish = new ChrisTestFinish();
    chrisTestFinish.setParam1(request.getParameter("param1"));
    chrisTestFinish.setParam2(request.getParameter("param2"));
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    chrisTestFinish.setTime(calendar.getTime().toString());

    model.addAttribute("command", chrisTestFinish);
    return getViewName();
}
```

This is the controller that renders the view that sets up the JSP shown above.

---

OK, so I looked at the generated action  from the form:form tag:

```
action="/chris/test1.htm?param1=value1&amp;param2=value4"
```

And realized that for some reason, the model was being built with 2 copies of value1, value4, one from the hidden inputs from form:hidden and one from that line, I believe.

I got rid of the 2 hidden inputs and things work, but I don't know the real root cause of what's going on though, so if anyone wants to explain I'd be grateful

Comment: Check your HTML source, heck how many `input` fields there are.

Comment: Theres only one input on the page, the one in my post

Comment: I'm not talking about your JSP, I'm talking about the generated HTML.

Comment: <input id="param1" name="param1" type="hidden" value="value1"/>
        <input id="param2" name="param2" type="hidden" value="value4"/>
        <input id="time" name="time" class="serverTime" type="hidden" value="Wed Oct 23 13:25:18 PDT 2013"/>

Comment: Interesting, more inputs have shown up but I don't see where multiple values would show up from

Comment: Those you've shown are normal. Spring converts `<form:hidden>` into `hidden` `input` fields.

Comment: The HTML standard for handling a post that has multiple `input`s with the same `name` is to post it as a comma separated list.  If you are seeing this in the post, it means the HTML is being generated with multiple inputs with the same `name`.  This should have nothing to do with Spring (although, it is possibly a problem with the Spring JSTL tags or something).